# How to trigger ViewModel command for a specific button events

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, command, mouseevent

How can a command on a ViewModel be invoked by a specific event of a button, such as `MouseDoubleClick`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `EventTrigger` in the *System.Windows.Interactivity* namespace, which is part of the so-called **Prism** framework. If you're just getting started with MVVM, don't care too much for Prism by now, but keep it in mind for later. Anyway, you can steel the `EventTrigger`

It works like this:

Reference the assembly *System.Windows.Interactivity.dll*

In XAML, reference the namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Then in your Button or any other control, add a EventTrigger like this:

```
<Button Content="Button">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandToBindTo}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameterToBindTo}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

This way, you bind your event to a *Command* on your DataContext.

**Remark**

To clarify the usage, here's a kind of real life example including the ViewModel. The fictional requirement is to allow the user to select an item in a list and then perform a command which takes the selected item as a parameter:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />

<Button Content="Do something with selected item">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                                                   ElementName=ItemsList}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

And that would be the ViewModel. Note how the parameter to the command is used, in the example with a generic version of a `DelegateCommand` object as you get it in every MVVM framework (sometimes `RelayCommand`). This class takes the type of the required parameter as a generic parameter (here `ItemViewModel`) and requires a method which takes an according parameter (here `ExecuteDoSomethingWithItem(ItemViewModel ...)`). The rest is WPF magic: The oject to which the `CommandParameter` property is bound in your XAML will be passed through as the parameter in your `Execute(...)` function.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _doSomethingCommand ??
                   (_doSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand<ItemViewModel>(ExecuteDoSomethingWithItem));
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand<ItemViewModel> _doSomethingCommand;

    private void ExecuteDoSomethingWithItem(ItemViewModel itemToDoSomethingWith)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        // Fill the collection
    }
}
```

Have fun with learning MVVM, it's worth it.

Comment: not supported in .NET 3.5, so how to do it in .NET 3.5 without Prism?

Comment: `.Interactivity` namespace is not .NET Core. Anyone know an alternative?

Comment: Yes. In NuGet in VS 2022 as of today, I see a warning symbol and a message stating that this package is deprecated, and that one should use Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf instead. It is even linked, so I can go straight to the new package.

Comment: Also, the package name is correct, but that full namespace doesn't exist within the package, so you must leave out the ".Wpf" part in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot of pluming yourself if you going to use Command and Event Binding from out of the box WPF.  You can gain a lot of just using existing framework such as [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), or [Cliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) that already provide command and even binding.

Answer (score -1):

you can use attached command behaviors

=> http://geekswithblogs.net/HouseOfBilz/archive/2009/08/21/adventures-in-mvvm-ndash-generalized-command-behavior-attachments.aspx