# How to bind command to button in WPF using Prism framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am trying to bind a click on button event in WPF to a command defined in a View Model, here is how I am doing that for now :

In the xaml code :

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Content="Module A" Background="Green" FontWeight="Bold">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChargeModuleDCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and in the ViewModel class :

```
class ModuleAViewModel
{

    public DelegateCommand<object> ChargeModuleDCommand { get; set; }

    public ModuleAViewModel()
    {
        ChargeModuleDCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(LaunchDModule);
    }

    private void LaunchDModule(object parm)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in the function");
    }
}
```

but it does not work. I've tried to do it as specified in this question : [How to trigger ViewModel command for a specific button events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122823/how-to-trigger-viewmodel-command-for-a-specific-button-events)
but it does not work either.
Is there any way that I can make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding ChargeModuleDCommand}" 
    Content="Module A" 
    Background="Green" 
    FontWeight="Bold"
    />
```

If `ModuleAViewModel` is the Button's `DataContext`, that should work.